# When asking for input and then inporting that variable to another file, the original file gets ran twice

Tags: python

I'm trying to import the variable from the original program(program.py) but it loops all code in program.py before moving on to newProgram.py. Any help would be appreciated (This only happens when the variable being imported comes from an input)

An example of this problem is:

```
# in program.py
question = input("Your greeting: ")
print("Hello")
import newProgram

# in newProgram.py
from program import question
if question == "Hi":
  print("Why does it loop original file") 

# This outputs:

Your greeting: Hi
Hello
Your greeting: Hi
Hello
Why does it loop original file
```

Comment: You shouldn't have circular imports. Importing a file runs all the code in it.

Answer (score 0):

the code runs twice because of the third line in `program.py`:

```py
import newProgram
```

This import runs the `newProgram.py` script again (which runs the `program.py` script).

So, if you're not using it, just get rid of this line and the code will work as expected.